# how to parse JSON containing international characters in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to parse the following json:

```
{"success":"true","message":"\u062e\u0648\u0634 \u0622\u0645\u062f\u06cc\u062f!"}
```

in a react-native project using the following code:

```
 fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                success = JSON.parse(responseJson['success']);
                message = JSON.parse(responseJson['message']);

                this.setState({ loading: false });
                alert(message);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
        });
```

i can easily display the value of 'success' key but i constantly receive this error: 'JSON Parse error: unrecognized token' while trying to access and display value of 'message' key.

Comment: how do you send this json message? you may need to escape `\ ` in json

Comment: `JSON.parse(responseJson['message'])` should just be `responseJson['message']`. Why do you think you have to pass it to `JSON.parse` again?

Comment: @FelixKling you're completely right. and solved the problem. i would accept, if you  submit as answer.thx